# Dojo combobox not working with latest browsers

Tags: javascript, html, web, dojo

I am working with dojo 1.6 and created a page containing only a combobox.

When I run it on Firefox 3.5 it works and all the theme related things and functionality of dojo is working fine.

But in Firefox 3.6 and chrome latest, theme and functionality(autosearch) of combobox is not working.

Here is my code:

```
  <head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js" djconfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.require("dijit.form.ComboBox");
            dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dijit/themes/tundra/form/Common.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dijit/themes/tundra/form/Button.css" />
        </head>

    <body class="tundra">
        <p>Combox Box</p>
        <select dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="fruit" name="fruit">
            <option>           Apples           </option>
            <option>           Apricot           </option>
            <option>           Aarro           </option>
            <option selected>  Oranges          </option>
            <option>           Pears       </option>
            <option>           Mango       </option>
            <option>           Banana       </option>
        </select>

         <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button">Click Me</button>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine in every browser...  if accessed via http://, and not locally with file://. Try to view your page via http, either by uploading it to a remote server, or by using a local [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) installation ([XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is great for development, and only runs when you explicitly request it to do so, so won't bog your system).

PS - I don't think you need these two lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dijit/themes/tundra/form/Common.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dijit/themes/tundra/form/Button.css" />
```

because these are automatically loaded for you.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually I am not running this code under any server like XAMPP etc. I am running it simply as we do a simple HTML page. Do I need to build this code?

Comment: @imran, you just need to access the page via http, which you can do by uploading your files to a remote server, or working with a local server on your computer (XAMPP, etc). If you are accessing the page directly from a folder on your computer, it will not work. You don't need to build or compile anything, just load the page via http.

Comment: Yeah after running from server it works. What could be the reason that Dojo did not work properly outside the server?